# Why does Swift Playgrounds return an error when trying to load in an image for a SKSpriteNode object?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I am currently making a game with Swift Playgrounds for the iOS platform. However, I am having troubling loading in image data for an SKSpriteNode. I would set it as a SKTexture:

```
DoctorBrown.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "WelcomeToTheDelorean")
```

It used to work fine, but now it doesn't (not sure why). When I run the program, it runs fine and the rest of the game works. But this node and its images do not and return a silent error (does not interfere with building or running of the game). This is the message (not the error itself):

```
Unable to get image data for DoctorBrown
```

As for the error, theres just a red '!', no error message.

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: That means the asset does not exist in your XCAssets

Comment: @Knight0fDragon it does though, I can manually put it in the scene and it loads properly, and when I do `print(DoctorBrown.texture)`, it prints out the file name and its actual dimensions.

Comment: Then you probably have a spelling error, which is why drag and drop works but not manually